# How to keep on reminding the boss about my work which he is supposed to review?

Tags: professionalism

Last time I sent him a mail regarding some of my work which was supposed to be reviewed by him. He forgot, and I didn't know that he had forgotten.

After 3 days he told me that I should keep on reminding him as long as it takes, if he doesn't respond in time.

Now, I don't want to irritate myself, and I don't want him also to get irritated by my constant reminders.

What is the way to keep on reminding him without getting me irritated or without making him irritated?

We use Whatsapp and mail, and he sits next to me.

**Am I supposed to remind him every 15 minutes, or once a day, or after every 2 hours?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if your boss told you to remind him, you should do that ocassionaly, as [Masked Man's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/84262/53782) suggested. About the frequency, I'd choose depending on the urgency of the task and whether this review is blocking other work. I also sit next to my boss, and she is eve so busy! In my case:

- Low priority: once/twice a week
- High priority once/twice a day
- Blocking priority: every 30/60 minutes

Additionally, since you are sitting next to each other you could think of another type of **passive reminder**. It could happen that every time you remind him he's busy and any time he's free, you don't remind him.

> For instance, what if you write *"Review issue #1206 (Low/High/Blocking priority)"* in a post-it and stick it to a pen in your pen holder, facing him?

That way the reminder is in his field of view and when he's free he'll look around and see it. For me, this is specially useful for high/blocking tasks, because reminding her every 30-60 minutes makes me feel like I'm annoying, so instead, every 30 minutes I noticeably add a new exclamation point to the post-it. That way I subtly catch her attention, both with a more urgent message and with my very act of adding stuff.

Depending on the size of the team, **I'd additionally recommend using tracking software**, like [Mantis Bug Tracker](https://www.mantisbt.org/), where you can mark items for review by another user and prioritize them. If all your team gets in the habit of checking it, it can be really useful. Sure, it takes a bit of extra time to create the issues and change the state but for us (10 dev team) has worked great :)

Answer (score 2):

Your boss has clearly told you to remind him as many times as it takes, so do that. If he sits right next to you, just turn around and ask him.

> Hey <Boss' name>, I am waiting for you to review my code changes for issue no. 12345.

Leave it at that. Don't try to "justify" why you are reminding him, or "apologize" for reminding him too often. Repeat as often as needed without feeling irritated or guilty.

Don't overthink this. The boss is clearly more concerned about the work getting done, as a good boss should be, and shouldn't mind being reminded once too often, especially since he has clearly told you so.

By the way, it would be rather odd to use WhatsApp or email to send simple messages to a person sitting next to you, especially if he is your boss, but if that floats your boss' boat, doing that would also be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your boss has told you what to do: keep on reminding him. He's not going to be annoyed by you doing what you were asked to do. In fact, he'd quite reasonably be annoyed if you *didn't* keep reminding him.

So just keep on reminding him, using whatever method seems most appropriate. This ain't rocket science.

Comment: This is rocket science. Am i supposed to remind him every 15 minutes, or once a day or after every 2 hours?

Comment: That's a judgement you've got to make based on how urgent your request is, how busy your boss is, etc, etc, etc.